# List cite aliases next to bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I have the `natbib` package for my citations. I have defined some alias like this:

```
\defcitealias{source-name}{SN}
\defcitealias{source-name2}{SAN}
```

And I cite using this alias:

```
\citepalias[][]{source-name}
```

I generate the bibliography with this:

```
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{newapa}
```

However, I want to put the alias in my bibliography next to the entry.
At the moment it looks like this:

```
Some name, 2001, some publication, 
pp.111-666.
Some other name, 2002, some other publication, 
pp.222-444.
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
SN          Some name, 2001, some publication, 
            pp.111-666.
SAN         Some other name, 2002, some other publication, 
            pp.222-444.
```

So the reader can see which source has which alias when he looks at the bibliography.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed it with replacing the `natbib` with the `biblatex` package.

Thats what I added:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt,
backend=bibtex
]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % you may change the name depending on your bibtex file
begin{document}
...
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] % put this where you want the table of contens
```

If you used the `natbib` package before, do the following:

1. Replace every `\citepalias[][p. 1-2]{source-name}` with `\cite[][p.
   1-2]{source-name}`
2. Remove those lines (if you have them)

   ```
   \usepackage{natbib}
   \setcitestyle{square}
   ...
   \defcitealias{source-name}{SN} % remove every defined alias because `biblatex` will generate it depending on the author name
   ...
   \bibliography{bibliography}
   \bibliographystyle{newapa}
   ```

If you have entrys in your `bibtex` file without authors you can define the alias manually with adding `shorthand = {ALIAS},` to those entrys. They can look like this:

```
@misc{anyname:year,
  shorthand = {anyname:year},
  title = {{Some Title}},
  howpublished = {\url{http://example.com}}
```